# i dont understand this javascript return statment. its using this arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, return-type

can anyone explain this javascript syntax. i dont understand that return statement. Is "person" an argument to the function? if 'yes', from where it is passing? there is no person variable in this component. At least an elaborated version of that return statement will also help. so that i can understand

```
const filterBy = (term) => {
    const searchTermLower = term.toLowerCase()
    return (person) => Object.keys(person).some(prop => 
        person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTermLower) !== -1
    )
}
const filterPerson = persons.filter(filterBy(searchTerm))
```

here presons is an array of objects and search term is a string.

```
const persons=[
{ name: 'abc', number: '123456' },
{ name: 'def', number: '44233' },
{ name: 'xyz', number: '345345' },
{ name: 'npe', number: '12312' }]
```

later im using this returned filterPerson for later processing. code is runnin totally fine but
this arrow function in return is what confusing me. im okay to update question if any more data is needed.

Comment: Returning a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's just an alternative way of writing the following function in simplest terms:

```js
const persons = [{
    name: 'abc',
    number: '123456'
  },
  {
    name: 'def',
    number: '44233'
  },
  {
    name: 'xyz',
    number: '345345'
  },
  {
    name: 'npe',
    number: '12312'
  }
];

const searchTerm = 'abc';
const filterPerson = persons.filter((person) => {
  const searchTermLower = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
  return Object.keys(person).some(prop => person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTermLower) !== -1)
})

console.log(filterPerson);
```

If you notice carefully, I'm passing an anonymous function to the `persons.filter` function. So if I want to get all fancy, I can just write that anonymous function as a separate block and return that entire function to the `persons.filter` function for it to be called in multiple places in my code. Which is exactly what has been done in the snippet you posted in the question.

**Here's me trying to be all fancy**:

```js
const persons = [{
    name: 'abc',
    number: '123456'
  },
  {
    name: 'def',
    number: '44233'
  },
  {
    name: 'xyz',
    number: '345345'
  },
  {
    name: 'npe',
    number: '12312'
  }
];

const myFunctionThatWasPreviouslyAnonymous = (term) => {
  const searchTermLower = term.toLowerCase()
  return (person) =>
    Object.keys(person)
    .some(prop => person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTermLower) !== -1)

}

const searchTerm = 'abc';
const filterPersonFancy = persons.filter(myFunctionThatWasPreviouslyAnonymous(searchTerm));
console.log(filterPersonFancy)
```

Comment: can you say what is the value of 'person' at an instant

Comment: yes. Person will be basically an element from the persons array at each iteration. `Array.filter` basically tests each item from array against a condition. Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to show you how `Array.filter` works.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxkau3vc/) to understand better. @legacy

Comment: by element, whether person can be an object from that array?, checking fiddle

Comment: Bingo! `person` is just a variable name. I can rename it to `legacy` and at each iteration it will hold one of the elements from the array. In our case the person object from the persons array at each iteration.

Comment: its function argument, got it

Comment: @legacy Accept the answer so that it may help others. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It is called higher-order function.

You have no issue understanding what this means right:

```
let increment = x => x+1;
```

Now imagine that you have a function, which **instead of returning incremented value as above, returns another function**, how would you write it? Simple:

```
let adder = x => y => y+x;
```

Usage:

```js
let adder = x => y => y+x;
let add5 = adder(5);
console.log(add5(9));
```

This example also relies on concept of closure: `x` is a closure (notice how it is remembered when I call `add5` with 9 and returns 14), that is a different topic, but shouldn't stop you from grasping what higher order function means.

> Is "person" an argument to the function? if 'yes', from where it is
> passing?

Your `person` is same as `y` in my case. So when is `y` passed? Answer: When I invoke `add5`, and its value is 9.

---

To refer exactly to your example, you want to know what is `person`.

*Example 1*

Here:

```
[1,2,3].filter(person=>person)
```

What is value of `person`? 1,2,3 right?

Now replace function `person=>person` with this:

*Example 2*

```
let filterBy = ()=>person=>person; // Higher order function, just first function doesn't take a parameter
[1,2,3].filter(filterBy())
```

The difference between example 1 and example 2 is in example 1 I directly wrote the function, in example 2 I generated it by calling `filterBy()`.

Comment: yes, i kind of understood how it goes, this term higher order function itself is helping and your usage part made it clear. but i have a doubt. in my question what is the value is varable 'person'

Comment: @legacy check my answer below, you will get a clear understanding of the syntax. If it clears all your doubts please accept the answer so that it may help others in future.

Comment: im checking it. it looks simple though, it blows my head. lemme take some time